# building more than one target in makefile

Tags: makefile

I need a GNU makefile to generate different libraries based on the file list.

My directory structure looks like :

```
-parent_dir
   -inc
   -src
   -lib
 -build_dir
```

I have all the sources dumped in the src dir. 
I need to make three different target based on different files.

```
SOURCES_TARGET_1 := 1.cpp \
                    2.cpp
SOURCES_TARGET_2 := 3.cpp \
                    4.cpp
SOURCES_TARGET_3 := 5.cpp \
                    6.cpp
```

All the targets have the same rule. Only thing that differs is the include files and source file list.
How can i do this in a generic way by defining rules that can be applied to src list.

Comment: Which *make* implementation? GNU? BSD? SysV?

Comment: The "include files"? You mean the prerequisite header files? Do you want those file names bundled in variables too? It's really unclear what you have in mind here.

Comment: @Beta yes, those are the include header files required for compilation.